# How to remove child processes from an array after they return?

Tags: c

So, I have the below function (named checkStatus()) that runs at the beginning of a while loop each time it loops through. It prints out the actively used parts of the array, where the child process ID's are stored. Also, if the child process has exited, it prints out the status of the exit code.

The array is added to by simply doing something similar to this:

```
//If background process child is made, add to the array and add to tracker
 spawnpid = fork();
arrayBackgroundPids[sizeOfArrayTracker]=spawnpid;
sizeOfArrayTracker++;
```

The function code is here:

```
void checkStatus()
{
    int backgroundStatus;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<sizeOfArrayTracker;i++)
    {
            printf("ArrayPosition: %d\n", arrayBackgroundPids[i]);
            fflush(stdout);
            if(waitpid(arrayBackgroundPids[i], &backgroundStatus, WNOHANG))
            {
                    if (WIFEXITED(backgroundStatus))
                    {
                            printf("background child exited with status of %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(backgroundStatus));
                            fflush(stdout);
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Also, Array is declared like this:

```
int arrayBackgroundPids[500];
```

However, my program doesn't remove the ID after they have exited. Ultimately, all I want the array to do is to store the active child ids. If the child id give an exit code when the loop runs, I want that id removed from the array after the exit information is printed. Also, child processes can end at any time. So sleep 15 could be in position 0 of array and sleep 20 could be in position 1. So, in that case, position 0 would exit before position 1. Also, the vis versa could happen as well.

Ultimately, I just want an array that dynamically expands and contracts when ids are added and removed (after an exit code prints) from that array.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Why not just use `memmove`?

Comment: Could you expand further on how that would work or how that is relevant to this? Not saying it isn't, but don't know how that would work with this code and not familiar with it.

Comment: Ahh. So now we've reduced a hard question to an easy question. Your real question is "what is memmove and how do you use it?". Your favorite search engine will help you. Short answer, it can "slide" all the entries past the one you're removing down to leave the remaining ones contiguous.

Comment: I have googled this, memmove would seem to not help me if something in the middle was removed from the array. Say I have array of size 10. I remove array[5]. Well, how am I going to really slide that if I am removing something from the middle with memmove? Seems it's more relevant to if you are removing stuff from the ends of the array. Unless I am wrong, which is 100% possible and I am not aware of how to do it from the middle.

Comment: You move all the entries past the one you're removing back one entry.

Comment: FYI: waitpid() can return: a pid of the exited child, zero if specified child has not exited, or -1 upon error.  Your "if" statement that contains "waitpid()" does not handle the "-1" return.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way could be to "invalidate" a Pid in the array once the process has exited. Let's say we interpret a value `0` as "not being a valid process id", then the code could look as follows:

```
        if(arrayBackgroundPids[i] && waitpid(arrayBackgroundPids[i], &backgroundStatus, WNOHANG))
        {
                if (WIFEXITED(backgroundStatus))
                {
                        arrayBackgroundPids[i] = 0;
                        printf("background child exited with status of %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(backgroundStatus));
                        fflush(stdout);
                }
        }
```

Of course, variable `sizeOfArrayTracker` does then not directly reflect the number of active processes. If you needed this number, it could be evaluated easily on the fly.